Bijectivity of $f(x) = α^qx + αx^q$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$
Let $q$ be an odd prime power and $α\in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ nonzero. Define the map
$$f(x) = α^qx + αx^q.$$
I am supposed to show that $f: \mathbb{F}_{q^3} \to \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ is bijective.

My attempt: It is enough to show that $f$ is injective, surjectivity follows from a cardinality argument. Now suppose $f(x) = f(y)$, hence
$$0 = α^q(x-y) + α(x^q - y^q) = α(x-y)^q+α^q(x-y)=α(x-y)\left[(x-y)^{q-1}+α^{q-1}\right].$$
All I'd need to show now is that the latter factor $(y-x)^{q-1}+α^{q-1}$ is nonzero for any choice of $x,y\in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$, which is where I am stuck. To no avail, I tried to write everything as a power of a primitive element (the addition is annoying) and also to express everything in a basis containing $α$, but same problem here.
Edit: I also don't see where to use $q^3$; I noticed that $q-1$ divides $q^3 - 1$, but how is this useful?
Any hints or ideas?

Suppose $x\ne y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$. Then (you have a sign error)
$$\alpha^q(x-y)+\alpha(x-y)^q=0,$$
so
$$\alpha^{1-q}(x-y)^{q-1}=-1.$$
In other words, you are saying $-1\in(\mathbb F_{q^3}^\times)^{q-1}$. But recall that $\mathbb F_{q^3}^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $q^3-1$, so $(\mathbb F_{q^3}^\times)^{q-1}$ is a cyclic group of order $(q^3-1)/(q-1)=q^2+q+1$. But this does not have an element of order $2$, since $q^2+q+1$ is odd!

This is surely the way to go :-)

Thank you! I fixed the sign error.

This answer doesn't add much to Kenta's solution. Posting it mostly to draw attention to:

the use of linearity, and
the role played by the Frobenius automorphism.


Denote $L=\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$, $K=\Bbb{F}_q$, when $L/K$ is Galois, and the Galois group is generated by the Frobenius map $F:L\to L, x\mapsto x^q$.
The first thing that caught my attention is the appearance of $F$. This readily implies that $f$ is a homomorphism of additive groups, a $K$-linear transformation even. Therefore injectivity is equivalent to having a trivial kernel.
When the Frobenius appears one recurring trick is to apply it an appropriate number of times, here thrice.
Let's assume that $x\in L$ is in the kernel of $f$. This gives us
$$x^q=-\alpha^{q-1}x.\tag{1}$$
Applying $F$ to $(1)$, and using $(1)$ to simplify $x^q$ yields
$$
x^{q^2}=-\alpha^{q^2-q)}x^q=\alpha^{q^2-1}x.\tag{2}
$$
Repeating the dose leads to
$$
x^{q^3}=\alpha^{q^3-q}x^q=-\alpha^{q^3-1}x.\tag{3}
$$
We then recall two things: $F^3$ is the identity on $L$, so the left hand side of $(3)$ simplifies to $x$. Also, $\alpha^{q^3}=\alpha$ and therefore $\alpha^{q^3-1}=1$. Hence $(3)$ simplifies to
$$
x=-x,
$$
implying that $x=0$ (we need $q$ to be odd at this point), when the claim follows.

Final remarks:

the claim is false when $q=2^m$ for in that case the kernel of $f$ is the $1$-dimensional subspace (over $K$) spanned by $\alpha$,
as seen from Kenta's answer, using the cyclicity of the multiplicative group often leads to a simpler argument when we are looking for zeros of a binomial.


Thanks for the insight! Really helpful remark regarding the Frobenius map, I will keep that in mind!

Just some generic stuff:
Say we have $L$ field, $\phi\colon L \to L$ morphism, and the additive map
$$x\mapsto \alpha \phi(x) + \beta x$$
Can it have a non-zero $x$ in the kernel?  That is equivalent to
$$\frac{\phi(x)}{x} = -\frac{\beta}{\alpha}=\colon \gamma$$
Now, assume that $\phi$ has finite order $d$, that is $\phi^d = \operatorname{Id}$. Then from the equality above we get
$$\gamma \cdot \phi(\gamma) \cdot \cdots \cdot \phi^{d-1}(\gamma) = 1$$
In our case, the expression turns out to be $-1\ne 1$, so such $x$ does not exist.

Let's also check by hand that if $\gamma$ satisfies the above condition then $x\ne 0$ exists with $\gamma = \frac{\phi(x)}{x}$.  (Hilbert's 90)
Indeed, consider the $d$ distinct morphisms of $L$ $\operatorname{Id}$, $\phi$, $\ldots$, $\phi^{d-1}$. They are linearly independent ( Artin's lemma).  Let's consider the following non-zero elements of $L$
$$p_k = \prod_{i=k}^{d-1} \phi^{k}(\gamma)$$
with $p_0 = 1$, from the above.  Since the linear combination $\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} p_k \phi^k(\cdot)$ is not identically $0$, there exists $y \in L$ such that
$$x \colon = \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} p_k \phi^k(y) \ne 0$$
Now one checks easily that $\phi(x) = \gamma \cdot x$.
